# Dual Libreoffice Writer Icons

Tags: icons, launcher, libreoffice

There are two Libreoffice Writer icons in my system. Only one of them works to launch it. The other causes the mouse cursor to become a spinning wheel for ten seconds, before reverting to the normal arrow, and the application does not get launched.

In this screenshot of the Favorites bar it is the lowest icon that does not work:

[image]

In this screenshot of Dolphin it is the highlighted menu item that works. The first choice icon to the upper left of it does not:

[image]

In this screenshot of "Show Applications" the highlighted left most Libreoffice Writer icon does not work, but the one to its right does:

[image]

When Libreoffice Writer is launched using the icon that works, it is the second launcher icon that doesn't work that gets the red dot to show an instance is running. No red dot appears on the functioning launcher icon.

I need to get rid of the nonfunctional icon in all of the above three instances. What is the best way to do that? I am concerned there may be a nonfunctional software installation somewhere I would want to clean up. How would it be found? When I right click on the nonfunctional icons and select "Show Details" the "Software" application's window opens which is not able to find the icon's application in the computer, or anywhere for download. It shows the message "Sorry! there are no details for that application".

My OS is Ubuntu 22.04. The Libreoffice Writer version that does open is:

Version: 7.5.3.2 (X86_64) / LibreOffice Community
Build ID: 50(Build:2)
CPU threads: 32; OS: Linux 5.17; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Ubuntu package version: 4:7.5.3~rc2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1~lo1
Calc: threaded

I attempted to remove the installations by using the recommended commands given in the responses below. Here is the result:

```
stephen@stephen:~$ sudo snap remove libreoffice
[sudo] password for stephen: 
snap "libreoffice" is not installed
stephen@stephen:~$ sudo apt remove libreoffice && sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
stephen@stephen:~$
```

In spite of this, the system Software application nevertheless shows there is a Libreoffice installation:
[image]

And the two Libreoffice Writter icons are still there.

Comment: Try `sudo apt remove libreoffice` and `sudo apt autoremove`. How many icons do you have now? Please report back ( later you can reinstall libreoffice with `sudo apt install libreoffice libreoffice-gtk3`)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you have two icons for LibreOffice is that one is installed through the traditional APT system, the other through SNAP.

From the version you report, it is the SNAP install (version 7.5.3.2) that works. The APT version in 22.04 is the 7.3 series. That one normally should also work for sure. It is impossible to tell at this point why it does not work on your system.

Using "Ubuntu Software", you can install/remove any of these versions. Search "Libreoffice". The APT version appears as the various parts, which can/should be individually removed. The SNAP version appears as the "Libreoffice" with the bland, white icon.

While you cannot see the software source from the overview in "Ubuntu Software", you can when you click on an item. The source is shown in the header bar.

Thus, in your case, remove the LO components installed as APT. Through the command line, it might be easier:

```
sudo apt remove libreoffice && sudo apt autoremove
```

To remove the SNAP version instead, you would use:

```
sudo snap remove libreoffice
```

Comment: The working launcher icon opens the Libreoffice that was installed by Discover.  The apt command you gave did indicate it had removed something. The the second nonfunctional launcher icon still exists. The snap command you gave responded with 'snap "libreoffice" is not installed'. I used Discover to remove Libreoffice Writer. Its launcher icon did disappear, but the nonfunctional icon remained. I then used Discover to reinstall it, and its functional launcher icon reappeared.

Comment: One thing I should have mentioned when starting this thread, I have just now added, is when Libreoffice is launched, it is the nonfunctional icon that gets the red dot, not the icon that launched it.

Comment: I do suspect this problem is caused by an installation done by either apt-get, or snap, that was not properly removed. When I decided to use Discover to install Libreoffice I tried to remove one installed either apt-get, or installation files I downloaded. I do not recall which right now.

Comment: If you tell that a version installed using APT is 7.5.3.2, then that is not the version from the standard Ubuntu repositories. Perhaps from an added libreoffice PPA then.

Comment: I deleted the nonfunctional LibreOffice icon from the favorites bar by right clicking on it and selecting "Remove from Favorites". I used the "Software & Updates" app to remove a Libreoffice PPA that was there. But in Dolphin there are still two versions of LibreOffice in the menu when a LibreOffice text file is right clicked. The one at the main menu's top is the one that does not work. It is the one in the "Open With" submenu that does. How is the nonfunctional one removed? When I select "Other Application" there are two "LibreOffice Writer" entries under "Office".

Comment: You did several things, but none of these indicated in the answer.